# Given the vector space $\mathbb R_n[x]$, of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$ with real coefficients, with the following operations.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

> Given the vector space $\mathbb R_n[x]$, of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$ with real coefficients, with the following operations .

> $\forall f,g \in F(X, \mathbb K), \forall x \in X$, define $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$

> $\forall f \in F(X, \mathbb K), \forall x \in X, \forall \alpha \in \mathbb K$, define $(\alpha f)(x) = \alpha f(x) $

> Check that the sets below are subspaces of $\mathbb R_n[x]$:

> a) polynomials of degree equal to $k$, with $k \le n$;

> b) polynomials of degree less than or equal to $k$, with $k \le n$;

> c) {$p \in \mathbb R_n[x] \vert p(t) = p(1-t), \forall t \in R$}

If is a subspace then 0 belongs to subset, $x+y$ belongs to subset and $\alpha x$ belongs to subset.

a)

$a_0x^0+a_1x^1+...+a_kx^k + b_0x^0+b_1x^1+...+b_kx^k =(a_0+b_0)x^0+(a_1+b_1)x^1+...+(a_k+b_k)x^k=c_0x^0+c_1x^1+...+c_kx^k$

$\alpha(a_0x^0+a_1x^1+...+a_kx^k)= \alpha a_0x^0 + \alpha a_1x^1+...+ \alpha a_kx^k = c_0x^0+c_1x^1+...+c_kx^k$

b)

$a_0x^0+a_1x^1+...+a_{k-1}x^{k-1} + b_0x^0+b_1x^1+...+b_{k-1}x^{k-1} =(a_0+b_0)x^0+(a_1+b_1)x^1+...+(a_{k-1}+b_{k-1})x^{k-1}=c_0x^0+c_1x^1+...+c_{k-1}x^{k-1}$

$\alpha(a_0x^0+a_1x^1+...+a_{k-1}x^{k-1})= \alpha a_0x^0 + \alpha a_1x^1+...+ \alpha a_{k-1}x^{k-1} = c_0x^0+c_1x^1+...+c_{k-1}x^{k-1}$

c)

Is my solution to a) and b) ok? I don't know how to check c) $p \in \mathbb R_n$ so $a_0x^0 + ... + a_nx^n \to a_0(1-x)^0 + ... + a_n(1-x)^ n $? I'm kinda lost.

Thanks

Comment: For A:  What if $a_k+b_k=0$?  First thing to always glance at is "Is 0 in my space"

Comment: What even are your *answers* to a), b), c)?